# ZF2 - How to check if session remember me is still valid?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

Say a ZF2 authentication storage retrieves the session manager in order to set a TTL:

```
class MyAuthStorage extends Storage\Session
{
    public function setRememberMe($rememberMe = 0, $time = 1209600)
    {
        if ($rememberMe == 1) {
            $this->session->getManager()->rememberMe($time);
        }
    }

...

}
```

How can one check whether the remember me TTL has expired? The apidoc is unclear, should I use [isValid()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.4/classes/Zend.Session.ManagerInterface.html#isValid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get you specific answer to this cause there is no api for it (or I didn't found it). I found that *remember me* it is enabled by setting some positive number of seconds to session cookie lifetime. So using [this](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Session.Config.SessionConfig.html#getCookieLifetime) method of session config instance you can probably check if *remember me* is valid.

You can also take a look at tests that check *remember me* functionality.
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session/blob/705d440e71b33c5ec2cf39496e7cba72e76eccb9/test/SessionManagerTest.php#L422